# Why would foreign nations sign on to FATCA?

Tags: international-relations, taxes, citizenship

[According to the IRS](https://apps.irs.gov/app/fatcaFfiList/flu.jsf), nearly every country, and hundreds of thousands of financial institutions, have signed on to [FATCA](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/corporations/foreign-account-tax-compliance-act-fatca).

FATCA, in a nutshell, forces governments to give up financial data on people who are considered US persons - even if that person is also a citizen and resident of said foreign government.

My question is: why would any foreign government sign this agreement? What do they stand to benefit? It seems this deal is completely one-sided as it is only the U.S. who taxes their citizens living in foreign countries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The US was able to get cooperation because it made credible threats.

Specifically a 30% withholding for non-complying institutions. The US financial system touches a large part of the world, so for many institutions it could enforce meaning loses, and certainly make them non-competitive in the huge US market.

This is an issue on a national level too. If the withholdings went through on a large scale it could destroy economies. The same logic as other sanctions applies, the US having a bigger economy could be expected to better survive the disaster than most other places, and we are bold enough to try it.

So far as I can tell no one explicitly says they capitulated out of fear of these withholdings, but it is featured in some government explanations of why it matters. ([Canada](https://www.fin.gc.ca/afc/faq/fatca-eng.asp) and [Honk Kong](http://www.fstb.gov.hk/fsb/topical/doc/fatca-faq2_e.pdf))

Also it is not quite one sided, the US agreed to reciprocity in many cases, which might work out to a tax win especially for places with a wealth tax or with a large population in the US.